# On Android emulator app gives error “This app won't run unless you update google play services” alert

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have the build.gradle with Google play services version 9.+ and emaulator have google play service version 8.4.
When I try to run the app I keep getting the error "This app won't run unless you update google play services"

The emulator has target : Google API 23
CPU :Google API Intel Atom (x86_64)
From the app -> setting I am unable to update the Google play service version.

Comment: Goto sdk manager -> launch standalone sdk manger and update google play there

Comment: I tried it, installed Google Play Services under Extra folder, did not help. Is this what you wanted me to do?

Comment: Try downloading a new system image with latest google api

Answer (score 0):

You might need to choose some of the Google API services in the SDK manager.

[image]

Also, when you are selecting the image, be sure to use the custom images( NOT the recommended images).

[image]